# Uploading a file using PUT to SharePoint, is there anyway to get the 'Id' in one call?

Tags: rest

I'm uploading files to SharePoint (2010) Library using cURL using a command similar to this:

curl --ntlm --user username:password -T C:\temp\1807500010.pdf http://website/1807500010.pdf -verbose

With POSTMAN, I'm using the PUT method but not sure which Header to use to elicit a response back in the body. Right now, I get an empty body response (but the file does properly upload), however, I do receive some headers back such as the etag and resourcetag, etc.

I'm hoping to get the generated "ID" that is produced by SharePoint in the response, but so far, I have been unable to that in both cURL or with POSTMAN. Is this possible with one call? Or would I have to use the REST API to get those properties separately?